# interactive terminal for mac OS

Tags: gnuplot

It is true that the old fashioned `x11` terminal is the default and solely interactive terminal on Mac?
`qt` seems even deprecated https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/173946.

PS: I have no Mac, but colleagues who use my programs. But I'm starting to be ashamed to distribute it.

Comment: The post, including the comments, you linked, says, that the option `--qt` was deprecated in favor of `--with-qt`, not the terminal itself!

Answer (score 2):

Gnuplot interactive terminals that can be used on MacOS

- qt (IMHO the favored option)
- wxt (equally capable)
- x11  (as you say, kind of outdated)
- aqua (connects to Mac-specific AquaTerm app)

Any or all of these can be configured in at the time gnuplot is built. Each depends on prior installation of the corresponding support libraries or, in the case of AquaTerm, a separate app. Aqua is the most "Mac-like", but provides display only (i.e. no mousing operations).

Answer (score 1):

> It is true that the old fashioned x11 terminal is the default

The default terminal may be vary depending how you install it or how you set GNUTERM environment variable. And you can also change the startup behavior by specifying a terminal in ~/.gnuplot.

#### As for gnuplot installed via Homebrew

From the link in your question, I will assume that your colleagues are using Homebrew to install gnuplot.

Homebrew, since version 2.0, no longer provides the installation options (like `--with-x11` or `--with-qt` ) in the formulae included in homebrew-core. To be precise, see [this](https://brew.sh/2019/02/02/homebrew-2.0.0/).

> Homebrew does not have any formulae with options in Homebrew/homebrew-core.

Currently, if you install gnuplot from Homebrew, only `qt` terminal can be used as an interactive terminal, while `x11` and `wxt` terminals are disabled. There is no option to enable these with the `brew` command.

If you prepare your own Homebrew Formulae, it's a different story...

Comment: Thanks. Only from the link I know about homebrew. Are there other ways for installation? The user mentioned quartz. And what about `aqua` mentioned by @Ethan? The answers appear a bit contradictory to me.

Comment: Rather than asking about the various options here, please check how your colleagues have installed gnuplot. And please improve your question by reflecting them.

Comment: The default terminal may be vary depending how you install it or how you set GNUTERM environment variable. You can also change the startup behavior by specifying a terminal in ~/.gnuplot.

Comment: There is no contradiction between my answer and Ethan's answer. It simply means that Homebrew's gnuplot is compiled with only qt enabled as an interactive terminal, and x11, wxt, and aqua all disabled. I'm sorry, I don't know about other package managers as I don't use them.